# does there exist a compact, contractible subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that cannot be dissected into $4$ parts of equal area by perpendicular lines?

Tags: examples-counterexamples

There was a question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045205/show-that-a-convex-compact-set-in-r2-can-be-cut-into-4-sets-of-equal-area-by), to show that a convex subset of $\mathbb R^2$ can be cut into $4$ pieces of equal area. In an attempt to prove it, I tried to more or less apply a "ham sandwich approach" twice and deduce the answer.

The problem was that although I could find two perpendicular lines that bisected the area of any compact set,  I couldn't guarantee that these lines simultaneously divided the set into $4$ equal parts.

A friend of mine suggested considering a continuous map $f: S^1 \times K\to \mathbb R/(x \sim-x) ???$ (we couldn't decide on a co-domain) that took a line given by some angle with respect to the $x$-axis and a point in our convex subset $K$, and outputted the area swept out by a counterclockwise $90^{\circ}$ rotation about this line. Ultimately, we wished to look at the homology of $K$ since it is trivial and derive a contradiction. Yet this doesn't really use enough about convexity, only that $K$ is contractible.

**my question:**  I'm not looking for an answer to the original question, but instead I'm asking if someone can  exhibit a compact, contractible subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that cannot be dissected into $4$ equal parts by two perpendicular lines.

**Edit 1:** Since I deleted my answer, here is my "first impulse," which ended up being incorrect:

> **Step 1:** I claim that a single line can bisect the area of a compact set into two pieces of equal area.
>
> Since we know our set is compact, it is bounded and closed so we take
>   the minimal and maximal $y$ coordinate of our set: $y_{min}$ and
>   $y_{max}$. Then, all we want to do is consider a constant line
>   (parallel to the $x$ axis) that moves up slowly, starting from the
>   least y value and ending at the maximal one.
>
> In other words, some function $\mathbb R^2 \times [0,1] \to  \mathbb
> > R^2$  given by $(x,y,t) \mapsto (x,y_{min}+(y_{max}-y_{min})\cdot t)$.
>   Notice that $(x,y,0)=(x,y_{min})$ and $(x,y,1)= (x,y_{max})$
>
> Now, we consider a new function $g$ whose value at some time $t$ is
>   exactly the area of $X$ under the line (Here, you can take the
>   integral to be the area).
>
> $g$ is continuous, just because the area in any $\epsilon$ amount of
>   time is bounded by the extremal $x$-values.
>
> Now, since the values of $g$ vary between zero and the area of the
>   whole set, we apply the intermediate value theorem, to deduce that one
>   half of the area will be attained at some time $t \in [0,1]$.
>
> **step 2:** we do the same thing, except we take a vertical line and vary it. These two lines together will dissect our compact set into
>   $4$ parts, and they will be perpendicular.

Comment: Just because the problem asks you to show this for convex sets doesn't mean that it's NOT true for arbitrary compact contractible sets; it might just be that the proof's easier in the former case, and hence it was a more appropriate problem for a class at some level of study. (Offhand, I have no idea whether the more general statement is true.)

Comment: @John Hughes , youre correct. I think i subconsciously just didnt make room for that in my question because I didnt want to see a proof for the theorem, since it would spoil the fun of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**POSSIBLE SPOILER**

These are my thoughts so far on a possible solution to the more general problem. Don't read if you want to avoid polluting your own thoughts. I won't say here whether the remainder of this contains a complete solution -- you'll have to read to find out.

---

Consider this sketch of the situation: 
[image]

The region is blue; a bounding box for the region is drawn in black and parameterized by $uv$ coordinates; the crossing lines are red, and divide the plane into four quadrants named $A, B, C, D$, and the crossing lines are specified by three numbers: the $uv$ coordinates of the crossing, and $s$, which is proportional the angle from the ray that divides the $A$ and $D$ quadrants and the positive $x$-axis. We take this angle divided by $\pi/2$ to get a number $s$ between $0$ and $1$.

Now the set of all possible "crosses" corresponds to $(u,v,s)$ triples with all coordinates ranging from $0$ to $1$. The quadrants themselves are also functions of these coordinates, and I hope it's clear that 
$$
D(u, v, 1) = A(u, v, 0)
$$
because the $D$ quadrant, when the cross is rotated by $\pi/2$ ends up sitting where the $A$ quadrant was before rotation.

Letting $Q$ denote one quarter of the area of the blue region, we can define
$$F: [0, 1]\times [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \to \Bbb R^3: (u, v, s) \mapsto 
(a, b, c)
$$
where $a$ is the area of the intersection of $A(u,v,s)$ with the blue region, minus Q. Thus if $A$ cuts out one quarter of the blue region, then $a$ is zero. Similar definitions hold for $b$ and $c$. And if $a, b, c$ are all zero, then $D$ intersects a quarter of the blue region too. I'm going to say that for "nice enough" blue regions of the plane, $a, b, c$ are all continuous functions of $u,v,s$. ("Nice enough" might rule out things like the complement of a cantor-like set, but almost certainly includes everything with the property that the boundary is a finite union of nonintersecting Jordan curves.)

What we're looking for is then a $(u,v,s)$ triple with $F(u,v,s) = (0,0,0)$.

The domain is a cube in 3-space. If I can show that its boundary maps to an essential cube in $ \Bbb R^3 - \{(0,0,0\}$, then I'll know that there's a "cross" that splits the region's area as required.

Let's look at $a(u, v, s)$ on the $s = 0$ square of the unit cube: That square corresponds to moving the center of the cross around the black box, oriented at angle 0. Starting at the $(0,0)$ and going counterclockwise, $a$ goes from $3Q$ to $-Q$ to $-Q$ to $-Q$ to $3Q$. 
$b$ goes from $-Q$ to $3Q$ to $-Q$ to $-Q$ to $3Q$. $C$ goes from $-Q$ to $-Q$ to $3Q$ to $-Q$ to $-Q$. You can plot this as a quad in $abc$ coordinates, and do the same for each of the other faces of the unit cube. With luck, it'll turn out to be obvious why this ends up defining an essential map of the cube to $\Bbb R^3 - \{(0,0,0)\}$, but I don't have time to draw it all out right now, so I'm abandoning this for now.

Comment: This was very nice. I may have gotten a little bogged down in the details, but I think that the idea is here.

Comment: Seeing your comment elsewhere made me remember this question. Please see the answer I just added. As it turns out, I ended up pretty interested in this rough area of ham sandwich-esque problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no.  Draw a vertical line $A$ that bisects the set and a horizontal line $B$ that bisects the set.  If the quarters are equal we are done.  Otherwise the pairs of opposite pieces have the same area.  Rotate $A$ clockwise, sliding it to keep it dividing the area equally and similarly with $B$.  The lines will move continuously as a function of the angle of rotation.  If we started with the upper left quadrant too small, after we have rotated $\frac \pi 2$ the corresponding piece is the lower left quadrant, which is too large, so we must have passed through a point where the quadrants were equal.

Comment: That's the usual "proof", but the "sliding it so as to keep the area equally and similarly with B" is pretty loose. In particular, there's no guarantee that the "equal-division set" for one pair looks 1-dimensional, nor that if it's one-dimensional, it couldn't look like a sine curve, so that trying to remain on it as you move the center upwards may get you in trouble. I think you need a more algebraic proof to really make this work. But the idea is certainly in the right direction.

Comment: @JohnHughes:  You can show that there is a line at any angle dividing the set equally by using the mean value theorem.  It starts at one edge with all the area on one side and slides to the other with all the area on the other.  So there is a line in that direction with half the area on each side.  I think the only question is to be sure the lines move continuously as you change the angle.

Comment: Exactly...and that's the tough thing to show for a general set.

Comment: @JohnHughes:  I think you need some sort of measurability condition on the boundary, but after that the fact that sliding has more leverage than rotation will show continuity.  Rotating by $\Delta \theta$ can only change the area balance  by $\frac 12(r_1^2-r_2^2) \Delta \theta$ where $r_i$ is the distance from the center to the edge each edge.  Moving $\Delta x$ changes the area balance by $\Delta x (r_1+r_2)$, so a small change in $\theta$ can be compensated by a small change in $x$.

Comment: That's OK if the number of edges is finite. :) I spent a bunch of time during my PhD trying to make proofs of this flavor work, and seldom succeeded, so I'm very suspicious. Look at all those Kakutani-Yamabe-Yojubo theorems, which SEEM to have proofs like this, but are in fact a pain in the neck!

Answer (score 0):

Actually no real topological constraint is needed. Let $\mu$ be a finite borel measure on $\mathbb R^2$ such that any hyperplane has measure zero (absolutely continuous with respect to lebesgue measure (to get rid of continuity problems.) We will use the intermediate value theorem twice.

**The Configuration Space:** Consider the lines $ax+by=c$. 
To each point $(a,b) \in S^1$, we take 
$$H^+(a,b)=\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid ax+by \geq c\},$$

and choose $c$ so that  $\mu(H^+(u))=\frac{1}{2}\mu(\mathbb R^2)$ (which is possible by the IVT.) We define $H^{-}$ by flipping the inequality, and note that $H^{+}(-u)=H^{-}(u)$ for all $u \in S^1$.

However, viewing $S^1 \subset \mathbb C$, we can consider multiplication by $i$ (just for ease of notation.) Then $H(u)$ and $H(it)$ are orthogonal and determine quadrants indexed by $(\mathbb Z_2)^2=\{\pm 1, \pm i\}$: which are the intersections $S_{1}=H^+(u)\cap H^+(is)$ etc. Note that this construction is equivariant with respect to rotation:$S_{1}(it)=S_i(u)$.

Because $H(u)$ and $H(iu )$ both bisect, $\mu(S_1(u))=\mu(S_{-1}(u))$ and $\mu(S_i(u))=\mu(S_{-i}(u))$. Hence, it will suffice to find some $u$ so that the measures of $S_1(u)$ and the measure of $S_i(u)$ are equal.

Consider the continuous map $f:S^1 \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(u):=S_1(u) -S_i(u)=S_1(u)-S_1(iu)$.  However,  $f(iu)=-f(u)$, so the intermediate value theorem ensures a solution.

Comment: Your notation is a little confusing; I think that you mean "to each point $x = (a, b) \in S^1$, we take...", but then you re-use $x$ as a free variable inside the set-construction in the displayed equation. It might make better sense to say "To each point $u = (a, b)$, we take $H^{+}(u) = ...$. I might also have chosen a name like $Q_1(u)$ for the quadrants rather than reusing $S$, which appears in $S^1$.

Comment: The key step seems to be "Consider the continuous map $f$..." It's not clear to me why $f$ is continuous; it seems to me that this depends on the chosen value $c$ (which depends on the thing I've called $u$) being a continuous function of $u$. I suspect that your "hyperplane has measure zero" is exactly the right criterion...I just don't see why. :(  But we're clearly on the same page as far as the general idea goes. BTW, this has been on my "list of things to go back to" for about a year now, so it's nice to see progress!

Comment: @JohnHughes I’m really thinking about this as a restriction of the assignment $S^2$ to each half space. If you believe that this is continuous, I can try to write up a proof that that the map in question is ( it is a loop in $S^2$)

Comment: There is also a “geometry free” way that I think might work, that is more complicated and uses a lot more machinery, which if I have some time to write up this week, I will share :). Thank you for your comments and attention to detail.